# PHP: How To Disable Dangerous Functions

Tags: php, security

How can I disable the dangerous **eval** function? Can that be done using **ini_set** function?

Also how to disable following functions? Can we disable them using **ini_set** function?

```
allow_url_fopen  
allow_url_include
exec
shell_exec
system
passthru
popen
stream_select
```

**eval** is one of the most dangerous function that bad guys can use to exploit the things. There should be a mechanism to disable that without resorting to **php.ini** file; but is should be done programatically.

Well, guys I am looking for an answers suggesting disabling of these dangerous lovely fellows without going to **php.ini** file; I mean how to disable them at runtime or programatically?

Thanks in advance....

**Update**

Has anyone heard about PHP Shell Offender Script? It mainly used the eval function for the exploit. Hackers are able to run their PHP code on your site.

My question was that I don't want to disable the eval function from php.ini file altogether. For example, i have developed my own MVC framework. Now the framework users can specify from frameworks config file whether eval (and others) function should be disabled or not. So this is left to the choice of framework users. Once they specify to disable it; i should be able to disable the eval function programatically.

So that is the scenario. Looking for helpful answers/solutions.

Thanks Again.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I don't understand why you deleted user1438726's answer, especially as you gave no justification. If what he says is correct, this is a tremendously helpful answer. Was his answer wrong or did you just disagree with it?

Comment: @Sarfraz - the current accepted answer by Pascal is 100% incorrect.  eval cannot be disabled using `disable_functions` as it is a language construct rather than actual function.  Please change the accepted answer, and this is a dangerous misconception that will be leaving many to assume they've disabled eval() when they haven't.

Comment: `eval` is not a function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To disable functions, mainly for security reasons, you can use the [`disable_functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive in your `php.ini` configuration file.

But, as the documentation states :

> This directive must be set in php.ini
>   For example, you cannot set this in
>   httpd.conf.

I suppose this is too "internal" to be configurable anywhere else than in PHP... And as it's security related, it's up to the system administrator to configure it.

Still, the best security measure is to write clean/secure code, filter all input, escape all output... And not let anyone run their own code on your server !

Comment: I was looking for a solution without going to php.ini file.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is the accepted answer, it's simply wrong: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62397

Comment: Please consider updating this answer as it is misleading. Thank you.

Comment: @Wiz there is a comment in that thread that says "`eval` is not a function. It's a language construct". The bug was also closed as 'not a bug' hence this answer is correct

Comment: It appears you can also disable php functions for CLI scripts (e.g. Unit Tests) with a flag: `php -ddisable_functions=curl_exec,stream_get_contents vendor/bin/phpunit tests/foo` to force all tests to mock dependencies properly.

Answer (score 34):

Afraid you're pretty much stuck using php.ini to disable most of those. However, it gets worse. `eval()` is technically not a function, it is a language construct, so it CANNOT be disabled using `disable_functions`. In order to do that, you would have to install something like **Suhosin** and disable it from there.

A good webmaster should consider a security review to be an essential part of site setup. Do not try to completely abstract this away, people are lazy enough about security already. If you are going to use tools (like a webhost), you should take the initiative to have at least a cursory knowledge of how to manage one responsibly.

That said, there are some other things you can do to severely cripple most hack attempts, including:

-Disable `base64_decode()` using `disable_functions`. Now, there are ways around this, however the vast majority of hack scripts are generic in nature, and this will break about 95% of them as they require the existence of BOTH of these functions in order to operate properly. This does not mean that your server cannot be hacked, but in most cases it would incur the overhead of manually sniffing your server for vulnerabilities, and most hackers are playing the numbers and ain't got time for that (NOTE: some hackers do have time for that, this is not a magic bullet by itself).

-Filter all input for common other exploit string patterns like `&lt;?php`, which is frequently used to squeak by an opening php tag unnoticed. There are several such patterns. Best practice is to whitelist specific characters and reject all others on a per-input basis. At the very least, filter the aforementioned, null terminators, and possible sql injection strings such as `'; --` (do not assume that simply using pdo or mysqli is going to filter ALL injection attempts, there are still some ways to pull this off even if you are properly using prepared statements).

-Any directories that serve only media should have all script access disabled, and all uploads and media should be placed only in such a directory. It is better to whitelist only the acceptable media rather than blacklist scripts, as there are any number of ways to execute a script file (eg: `php`, `php5`, `phtml`, etc) which individually may or may not be available on any given server environment. You can do this with a simple .htaccess placed in the media directory similar to this:

```
php_flag engine off
AddHandler cgi-script .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .pl .py .jsp .asp .aspx .htm .html .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -Indexes -ExecCGI

<Files "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|tiff|swf|flv|mov|avi|mp4)$">
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</Files>
```

This part can be dynamically written by php, so your application would be capable of securing sensitive directories in a manner similar to this, which can mitigate a great deal of hacker pain, as this is typically overlooked. I typically add a similar .htaccess to almost every Wordpress site I work on in the uploads directory, and have often wondered why this is not done out of the box, as it blocks a great deal of hack attempts and does not interfere with the application in any way that I have noticed.

Unfortunately, if you are not on an apache server, you will need to find another solution (on IIS there is most likely an equivalent, but I am not aware of what it would be personally).

-You should also configure your .htaccess (or web.config/etc) to disable any access methods that are not needed for your specific application. If you are not doing RESTful web services, there is really no reason to allow `PUT` or `DELETE`, you should almost certainly also disable `TRACE`, and probably also don't really have any reason to leave `OPTIONS` or `HEAD` enabled either. It should also be mentioned that all non-recognized connection methods by default resolve to `GET`, which means that from the command line I can do something like:

```
curl -X BOOGITY -d arg=badstuff -d arg2=morebadstuff yoursite.com
```

In this example, `BOOGITY` is meaningless, however, your server will interpret this as:

```
curl -X GET -d arg=badstuff -d arg2=morebadstuff yoursite.com
```

However your application likely will not.
In order to prevent this, you should configure your server to accept only `GET` as `GET`, and not allow it to be the default.

In most cases, the primary point is not to make it difficult to execute specific php patterns in your environment, the point is to prevent the inclusion of rogue code (either locally or externally) so it does not become an issue. If you are allowing the installation of modules or such into your CMS, sloppy programmers WILL eventually create exploits, which you cannot really do much about aside from enforcing pretty stringent API parameters that make it very difficult to do it poorly, but it can never be made impossible. Never underestimate the capacity of an offshore hack shop or self proclaimed "php ninja" to diligently work with your system in the most insecure or non-compliant way possible, create massive vulnerabilities, and to invent any number of roundabout hacks to do so that are actually harder to pull off than just doing it the right way.

/security rant.

Comment: I added the `suhosin` module recently to Alpine Linux https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=php5-suhosin&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=

Comment: base64 is part of a lot of genuine web applications - not really possible to disable it in most cases

Comment: That is true. I only noted the tendency of viruses to routinely use it for obfuscation. You can also prevent malicious code by just not allowing files to be uploaded, or not allowing executables. Use as many precautions as you can afford for your own use case.

Answer (score 11):

In short: you can't do that.

But I think you don't really understand how eval and those functions are exploited. The problem occurs when programmers do not sanitize properly the ARGUMENTS that are passed to them.

The php shell offender script that you mentioned is just a simple PHP script passing arguments to those functions. But the attackers already had a way of injecting/uploading the malicious script. If you are not using these functions at all nor passing arguments from user input, attackers can't run arbitrarily code on your server using eval() or relatives.

Are you going to be hosting this framework for your users? If you are allowing users to upload and run code then you have a bigger problem in your hands.

Read about remote code execution and remote/local file inclusion here to learn more about attacks related to this: [Common PHP vulnerabilities](http://milw0rm.com/papers/381)

Comment: Sorry. Someone just uploaded malwares to my home testing server yesterday and a php to eval a shell command to open a `.exe`. I have no idea how those files got there because I have no script serving the uploads. Therefore, the hacker must have found some security holes to upload to my Apache server. I'm a noob at setting up servers but I'm finding ways to patch them.

Answer (score 8):

The disable_functions directive is only available in the [php.ini configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

To disable functions at runtime wouldn't make much sense, since you would be able to modify the disabled function list at runtime to re-enable functions as well.

Comment: @Metafr wrong, @Kenaniah is right, you CAN NOT modify it from a php file with `ini_set('disable_functions', '');` ! (and it all makes sense :p)

Answer (score 4):

You can [disable eval](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_diseval_extension) through https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_diseval_extension which is now php8 compatible via version 0.2.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your php.ini (you Search for 'disable_functions')

```
disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

Then restart your php service (apache or php-fpm)