# How do I disable a function(s) from usage in PHP?

Tags: php

I wanted to know the way to disable a function from usage in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865020/php-how-to-disable-dangerous-functions

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the `php.ini` configuration file, you can use the `disable_functions` parameter. For example, to disable the `symlink()` and `system()` functions, you would use:

```
disable_functions = "symlink,system"
```

Comment: Lol...Uh oh, now I have 666 reputation.

Comment: I want to support but I cannot. it says i need 15 score :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can give me more details, like what you are trying to do maybe we can provide a better solution. To answer your query if you want to disable a function this should do:

```
override_function('test', '', '');
```

this will override function test with a function that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to override that function to do nothing

http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php