# how can i make uploading plugin process secure

Tags: php

lets take the word press example
now when you want to add new plugin
you have to upload the plugin file (php file)
in that case, may some one evil
know your admin password and go to and upload a plugin
but not realy plugin
its evil code to hack your site

may we use function [like this](http://www.awcore.com/php/snippets/139/validating-files-source-or-content_en) to check the content , but i know know , may the other plugins contand the same code? or i can dsable some functions in it?

Comment: if some one kicked me and i gave him my password?

Comment: You cannot *reliably* check for "bad" code. Too many ways to obfuscate that, a simple blacklist won't do.

Answer (score 2):

By allowing someone to run their code in your project, some level of trust must be given.

What you're asking is already answered here: [PHP: How To Disable Dangerous Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865020/php-how-to-disable-dangerous-functions)