# Is there an option to make phplint fail if a var_dump is in the code?

Tags: php, phplint

We are using phplint to check our code and I am trying to find an option that would make it fail if there is a var_dump somwehere in the code. As I could not find an option for it, is there another way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is run it with it's own PHP.ini, and add that function to the disabled function list in that ini file.  [Disable functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865020/php-how-to-disable-dangerous-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static analysis tool such as PHP_CodeSniffer can (and should) be used to perform a check such as the one you describe.